# Can I configure both ElasticSearch and ChromaDB in a single django application?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, chromadb

I have read the documenations [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/](https://stackoverflow.com) but this page [https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://stackoverflow.com) describes how to use ElasticSearch.  That doesn't seem to allow multi db with elastic search.  I was also not able to find the settings for ChromaDB.

I am trying to build an application that can use LLM via langchain and chroma db, but I have a data source in JSON that I want to store in elastic search.

I am hoping to find a solution to use both elastic search for some models and chromadb for other models and potentially mysql for other models.

Currently I am thinking two or three instances of Django applications with a shared vue application accessing the REST interfaces corresponding to the models.  I would have one instance of django to handle user login and management and SSO for the other(s)